# How to provide authentication in Swagger API on Spring Boot application

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I have integrated Swagger to generate API documentation for Spring REST application using Spring Boot. It works well, I could see the generated API documentation when I hit the URL : http://localhost:8080/test/swagger-ui.html
My question is how can I restrict the access to the API? Basic authentication based on hardcoded username and password should be good enough for at least to start with. I used maven to add "swagger2" dependency.

Here is the pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>                                                                           
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>                                                      
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>                                          
    <version>2.7.0</version>                                                             
</dependency>                                                                          
<dependency>                                                                           
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>                                                      
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>                                        
    <version>2.7.0</version>                                                             
</dependency>
```

Here is the swagger config:

```java
@Configuration                                                                         
@EnableSwagger2                                                                        
public class SwaggerConfig {                                                           
    @Bean                                                                              
    public Docket api() {                                                              
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)                                 
          .select()                                                                    
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.eeocd.test.ws.resource"))     
          .build();                                                                    
    }                                                                                  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can enable authentication by adding a securityScheme and securityContext to the Docket object.

```
@Configuration                                                                         
@EnableSwagger2                                                                        
public class SwaggerConfig {                                                           
    @Bean                                                                              
    public Docket api() {                                                              
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)                                 
          .select()                                                                    
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.eeocd.test.ws.resource"))     
          .build()
          .securitySchemes(newArrayList(basicAuth()))
          .securityContexts(newArrayList(securityContext()));                                                                    
    }
private BasicAuth basicAuth() {
    BasicAuth ba = new BasicAuth("basic");
    return ba;
}

private SecurityContext securityContext() {
    return SecurityContext.builder()
            .securityReferences(defaultAuth())
            .forPaths(apiPaths())
            .build();
}

private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
    AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");
    AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
    authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
    return newArrayList(new SecurityReference("basic", authorizationScopes));
}



private Predicate<String> apiPaths() {
        return or(regex("/api/v1.*")
        );

    }

}
```